# How to generate multi band raster map from CSV

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, csv, pandas

I'm trying to generate a map from a CSV with percent land usages.

The CSV data looks something like the following:

```
Index   x       y       l1 l2 l3 l4 l5 l6 l7 l8 l9 l10  l11 l12 l13 l14 l15 l16 l17 l18 l19 l20 l21 l22 l23
195618  318500  1020500 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
195619  319500  1020500 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
195620  320500  1020500 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
195621  321500  1020500 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
195622  322500  1020500 0   0   0   19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0
195623  323500  1020500 0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
195624  324500  1020500 0   0   0   99  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I'm trying to figure out how to map this data so that the map will show the presence of land use types based on their percentage for that pixel.

This CSV was generated from a TIFF. I thought using a CSV format would be more accessible to users to peer into.

I've managed to write some code that will present one of the bands but I do not know how to illusrate multiple bands at the same time in an effective manner

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.chdir('filepath/')

df = pd.read_csv('labelled_lcm_2.csv')

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.iloc[0:, 1], df.iloc[0:, 2])]

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df.iloc[:, 4], geometry=geometry)

gdf.plot(column='l2')

plt.savefig('raster.tiff')
```

The result of the following code is this raster (not super proud of the way it looks but I guess aesthetics is a problem for another day):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiff filed are used to work on geoprojected images. Data projection are stacked inside. Gdal or rasterio are the most common librairies to work on such data. In your case i would iterate on every column and reshape them using numpy tools. Then i would stack all the outputs in a single array.

Then i would save this array as a tiff file. Keep in mind that you need geospatial information if you want to save a correct tiff file.

```
import numpy
import rasterio
import os

# function to write a numpy array as a raster file, tif in your example
def numpy_to_raster(array, outputdir, name, projection, geotransform, nodata = np.nan, tags = {}):
    n,m,c = array.shape
    profile = {'driver' : 'GTiff', 
               'width' : n, 
               'height' : m, 
               'dtype' : array.dtype, 
               'count' : c, 
               'crs' : projection, 
               'nodata' : nodata}
    
    geot = Affine(geotransform[1], 
                  geotransform[2], 
                  geotransform[0], 
                  geotransform[4], 
                  geotransform[5], 
                  geotransform[3])
    
    profile.update({'transform': geot})
    save_path = os.path.join(outputdir, name)
    with rasterio.open(save_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        for i in range(c):
            dst.write(array[:,:,i], i+1)
        dst.update_tags(**tags)

## your df is used here
lin_number = len(df['y'].unique())
col_number = len(df['x'].unique())

liste_array = []
liste_band = []
for column_name in df.columns:
    if column_name not in ['x', 'y', 'index']:
        array = df[column_name].reshape(col_number, lin_number)
        liste_array.append(array)
        liste_band.append(column_name)
        
# concatenation of every channel in a single array with channel as first dimension
array = np.stack(liste_array)  
# array with channel as last dimension 
array = np.moveaxis(array, 0, -1)
name = 'file.tif'
# used to keep the information of the channels in the saved file
tags = dict(zip(["band_{0}".format(i) for i in range(len(liste_band))], liste_band))
output_dir = ''

# you need the crs and the geotransform of your first tiff file to stock these informations in the new one you want to create

your_first_tif_file = rasterio.open(path_first_tif_file)
out_crs = your_first_tif_file.crs
geot = [*your_first_tif_file.transform]

numpy_to_raster(array, output_dir, name, out_crs, geot, nodata = np.nan, tags = tags)
```

Then, if you want to plot your map, you can use imshow from matplotlib when your are working with a numpy array. Or you can use show from rasterio.
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/plotting.html